# Haskell inserting into a specific tree

Tags: haskell, insert, binary-tree

I am having the following problem with my implementation of a tree in haskell. I have the data type correct and my insert and search methods work. However i am pretty limited when it comes to testing. For example if i declare a tree in the code say `testtree` and give it a number of values, when trying to insert into `testree` it never actually updates testree. Allow me to explain.
If i declare in the ghci window `insert 5 testtree`, it returns a new tree which was what testree was, with the 5 added in the correct position. Happy days. If i try to add another element however into testree, it returns what the original testree was with the new element added. The 5 has dissapeared. So the problem is i cant change the original instance of testree, which is a pain in the ass. Testing my insert method has consisted of creating numerous trees that cover all the possibilities of adding an element to them. If i could just have one tree that i can keep adding to it would be much more convenient. Any help would be much appreciated! heres a sample that highlights my problem, its a 2-3-4 tree i am implementing so ive taken out a lot of the code from this as its not needed in order to highlight the problem.

```
data Tree t =   Empty 
                | Root1 t (Tree t)(Tree t) 
                | Root2 t t (Tree t)(Tree t)(Tree t)
                deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

leaf1 x = Root1 x  (Empty) (Empty)
leaf2 x y = Root2 x y (Empty) (Empty) (Empty)

insert :: Ord t => t -> Tree t -> Tree t
insert t Empty = leaf1 t
insert t (Root1 a Empty Empty)
          | t <= a = leaf2 t a
          | otherwise = leaf2 a t

insert t (Root1 a left right)
          | t <= a = Root1 a (insert t(left)) (right)
          | otherwise = Root1 a (left) (insert t(right))

testtree = Root1 5 (Root1 3 (Empty) (Empty)) (Root1 7 (Empty) (Empty))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show us some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell values are immutable. When you define `testtree = ...` you cannot change the value of `testtree`.

Instead, you have to do something like this:

```
tree1 = insert 5 testtree
tree2 = insert 6 tree1
tree3 = insert 7 tree2
...
```

Note that if you try:

```
testtree = insert 5 testtree
```

you'll just get into an infinite loop as `testtree` on the RHS refers to the same `testtree` that is being defined.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the wonderful world of persistent data structures. The fundamental defining feature of a persistent data structure is that all updates are non-destructive. You can't change a data structure, only use it as a basis for a new one.

This turns out to have immense advantages in code maintenance, performance of parallel code, and correctness of concurrent code. It's a good thing.